# Unpacking of tuples of varying sizes in Julia

Tags: julia, tuples, unpack

I have a python code here :

```
>>> a, *b , c = (1,2,3,4)
>>> a
1
>>> b
[2, 3]
>>> c
4
>>>
```

Is there a similar facility available with Julia?

Same command in Julia is giving error : " * is not a unary operator"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `...` operator for this. (Requires Julia version 1.9 or above.)

```
julia> a, b..., c = (1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 2, 3, 4)

julia> a
1

julia> b
(2, 3)

julia> c
4
```